# WeakEventManager RemoveHandler does not always work when called asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am using the [`WeakEventManager<TEventSource, TEventArgs>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438(v=vs.110).aspx) class in order to subscribe to events in C#. Event subscription works fine, however calling [`WeakEventManager<TEventSource, TEventArgs>.RemoveHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from a `Task` does not always remove the handler - most (but not all) of the time the handler is still executed when the event fires.

This is illustrated in the following example.

```
public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler Fired = delegate { };

    public void FireEvent()
    {
        Fired(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static bool added, removed, handled;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            added = removed = handled = false;

            var source = new EventSource();

            AddHandlerAsync(source).Wait();

            RemoveHandlerAsync(source).Wait();

            source.FireEvent();

            if (removed && handled) Console.WriteLine("Event handled after removal!");
            else                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async static Task AddHandlerAsync(EventSource source)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Windows.WeakEventManager<EventSource, EventArgs>.AddHandler(source, "Fired", HandleEvent);
            added = true;
        });
    }

    private async static Task RemoveHandlerAsync(EventSource source)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Windows.WeakEventManager<EventSource, EventArgs>.RemoveHandler(source, "Fired", HandleEvent);
            removed = true;
        });
    }

    private static void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        handled = true;
    }
}
```

The handler is removed all of the time, however in most cases the event is still handled.

Am I making an error in the way that these methods are called? Do these methods support being called asynchronously? Is there an alternative approach that would work?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `WeakEventManager`'s are stored in a current `WeakEventTable` which initialized for the current thread ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/WeakEventTable.cs,1cd4086215999b0c)):

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static WeakEventTable   _currentTable;  // one table per thread
```

And you use the thread pool task sheduler which is the default sheduler. It calls `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` on the same thread sometimes. But sometimes it invokes `RemoveHandler` on a different thread and you have another `WeakEventManager` without the requested `EventSource`.

**NOTE:** If a type inherits from `DispatcherObject` then instances of this type depends on the thread in which they are created. If a `DispatcherObject` is singleton then it is created one per thread.

So if you see a `DispatcherObject` then call its methods only from thread in which it was created. Otherwise, you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I'm seeing this behaviour. How would I change the way I'm calling Add/RemoveHandler so that handlers are removed on the same thread?

Comment: Use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to invoke `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` methods.

Comment: There is no `Application.Current` in this example. Thanks for the tip about the `DispatcherObject` though - very helpful!

Comment: A `WeakEventManager` works properly only in a WPF application because a `Dispatcher` must exist to perform cleanup operations (`WeakEventManager` uses `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`). But if you want to know how to synchronize threads in a console app then read about [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link - that pretty much answers my question

Comment: One cannot stress enough: **So if you see a DispatcherObject then call its methods only from thread in which it was created. Otherwise, you will have problems.**

Comment: @YohDeadfall we are lucky we have you. The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.weakeventmanager-2?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) on `WeakEventManager<TEventSource,TEventArgs>` have nothing to say whatsoever about threading. There are only static add/remove handler methods on that class, implying there is one handler collection per type parameter pair, but in fact for the reasons you state, each thread will have its own separate list of handlers. Pure insanity!